# Trying To Merge Static Frameworks Using Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, static-linking, dylib, carthage

- `carthage version`: 0.25.0
- `xcodebuild -version`: 8.3.3
- Are you using `--no-build`? No
- Are you using `--no-use-binaries`? No
- Are you using `--use-submodules`? No
- Are you using `--cache-builds`? No

**Cartfile**

`github "rs/SDWebImage"
github "AgileBits/onepassword-extension"
github "hsousa/HCSStarRatingView"
github "sugoi-wada/facebook-ios-sdk" "780a72cd6086c57939d83a7143462ae13dfb9a74"
github "CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout"
github "card-io/card.io-iOS-source"`

I'm able to build my dependencies using a build script as outlined in the [documentation here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/StaticFrameworks.md). Now I'm trying to merge my static frameworks into a dynamic one and running into problems.

To start, I'm adding a single framework to the dylib target, I've disabled bitcode and added the following `OTHER_LDFLAGS`: `-all_load, -ObjC`. I'm starting small with the `HCSStarRatingView`. It has been added to they dylib target and that builds.

To test this new combined framework I've added an app target. I can import the framework target and the app target recognizes it. However when I try to declare a new view with `let view = HCSStarRatingView(frame: .zero)` I'm getting the following error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'HCSStarRatingView'`.

I'm assuming that I don't import `HCSStarRatingView` directly because it's now part of my framework target. I'm also assuming that I don't have to add anything to my dynamic framework target's umbrella header to expose the linked static frameworks inside. Are those assumptions correct? Any idea what I could be missing here?

Comment: Hey @jsorge, did tou ever figure this out? I wluld be interested on knowing how you solved the issue

Comment: @jsorge Got the same problem, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i think your assumption might be wrong.
I have a similar setup and got it working by importing both: dynamic framework and the static library that it depends on. eg:

```
 import framework-target
 import HCSStarRatingView
```

furthermore i had to make sure that the app target included the carthage build path